# Error in configuring network security xml in android

Tags: android, xml, security, networking

In the [android network security docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html) , it says to create a network_security_config.xml file in res/xml folder.

In order to make an entry in manifest file, it says to make an entry in this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But I am getting the error `No resource identifier found for attribute 'networkSecurityConfig' in package 'android'`

**I also checked for the valid attributes in application tag ( [android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) ), there is no attribute as "networksecurityconfig"**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set your `compileSdkVersion` to 24 or higher and set your `buildToolsVersion` to `24.0.0` or higher.

With regards to the documentation, that's a documentation bug.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is fixed, the xml should live inside res/xml which is not in the root but inside android/app:

`android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

From minimumSDK 20 you will need the file and be sure to whitelist localhost and 10.0.2.2 and 10.0.3.2 or you'll have trouble on development