# Network security config Expecting system, user or an @resource value

Tags: android, charles-proxy

I am currently trying to set up the Charles Proxy service for AndroidTV/FireTV but am facing an issue with specifying the certificate authority in the res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Every time I try to type @raw my IDE autocompletes to appNs (application namespace). I have tried invalidate/restart, cleaning/rebuilding, adding the appNs, specifying raw in the sourceSets in gradle, checking for updates to the compileSDK/build tools ([Error in configuring network security xml in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936253/error-in-configuring-network-security-xml-in-android)), but the app still refuses to resolve my resources.

EDIT: Although the resource ID isn't resolved, the app still compiles and crashes at runtime with the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.package, PID: 29431
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.my.package.tv.ui.TVAppClass: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse XML configuration from network_security_config
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5881).
```

followed by...

```
Caused by: android.security.net.config.XmlConfigSource$ParserException: Unknown certificates src. Should be one of system|user|@resourceVal at: Binary XML file line #6
    at android.security.net.config.XmlConfigSource.parseCertificatesEntry(XmlConfigSource.java:211)
    at android.security.net.config.XmlConfigSource.parseTrustAnchors(XmlConfigSource.java:226)
    at android.security.net.config.XmlConfigSource.parseConfigEntry(XmlConfigSource.java:280)
    at android.security.net.config.XmlConfigSource.parseNetworkSecurityConfig(XmlConfigSource.java:350)
    at android.security.net.config.XmlConfigSource.ensureInitialized(XmlConfigSource.java:101)
```

It will run fine with the "system" or "user" values but the SSL Proxy for Charles won't work.

Device Meta:

- Android Studio 3.3
- Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772, built on December 24, 2018
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 x86_64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- macOS 10.12.6
- compileSdkVersion 28
- buildToolsVersion 28.0.3

Comment: "res/raw/network_security_config.xml" -- that's not where that file goes. That XML goes in `res/xml/`, not `res/raw/`. Your certificate goes in `res/raw/`.

Comment: Sorry, @CommonsWare, that was a typo. It is located in res/xml, the pem file is in res/raw ... Also thank you to everyone at CommonsWare

Comment: If you ignore the autocomplete and just type in the desired value, do you get a build error? Also, thanks for the kind words (though there's only one of me here at CommonsWare...)!

Comment: I don't get a build error, but I get a runtime error - Caused by: android.security.net.config.XmlConfigSource$ParserException: Unknown certificates src. Should be one of system|user|@resourceVal at: Binary XML file line #6 - I'll add the full stack trace to my question. If I leave it as "system" or "user", the runtime error disappears but Charles won't work. In that case, thank you, Mark Murphy for all your helpful posts, books and answers! They have already saved me before!

Comment: I haven't tried that approach for Charles -- I use `user` and add the certificate to the certificate store via Chrome and Settings. What you have should work, though, and the Chrome-and-Settings approach may be a problem for TV-based devices. I don't know that I have used a PEM file for `debug-overrides`, though I definitely have for specific domains (see https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.13/Internet/CA/app/src/main/res/xml/network_selfsigned.xml for an example). So, unless that PEM isn't in `res/raw/`, I can't explain your results. Thanks again for the kind words!